# Android Studio: Adding @+id through Design GUI Generates Errors

Tags: android-studio

*I have found a workaround for this, which I will be posting as an answer, but it still raises the question of why it happened in the first place.*

When I try to add a new id through the Design GUI, I type the name into the box:

```
id_sample
```

As soon as I tab out of the box, it prepends `@+id/`:

```
@+id/id_sample
```

which sounds reasonable enough, because - hey, it's got to put in the instruction to add a new id per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html), right?

---

But when I go into the java code, autocomplete is giving me gibberish on the code side - because of the extra `@+id/`, autocomplete gives me `@+id/id_sample` for a grand total of

```
menu.findItem(R.id.@+id/id_sample);
```

which has invalid characters; while deleting them:

```
menu.findItem(R.id.id_sample);
```

gives the error `Cannot resolve symbol 'id_sample'` because the xml is insisting that the correct name includes the invalid characters. Catch 22.

So how do I properly reference an id?

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the xml, the `@+id/` actually gets added *to the `@+id/id_sample`*:

```
android:id=@+id/@+id/id_sample
```

which obviously gives the compiler a heart attack. Having figured out what was going on, it is easy (though tedious) enough to jump into the xml and delete the extra `@+id/` but I can't see any way to get the designer to put it in right in the first place.

Once this is corrected in the xml, it gets automatically corrected in the GUI, autocomplete will give you the correct name when you go into the java code, and the compiler will recognize it.

All that's left is to wonder if there is something I'm doing wrong that is causing this. Is this a known (or unknown) bug? Knowing what is wrong, it can be fixed in the xml, but it seems the GUI should have gotten it right in the first place. Right?

Comment: This is unlikely. Because R.id is static java class and every resource id that you generate through the xml files have to be declared under id inner class. I guess the studio couldn't add this because it isn't a valid variable name but more likely it could be in the auto complete list.